# How to pass Meteor Spacebars helper with parameter into another helper attribute?

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze, spacebars, meteor-helper

everybody :) For example I have something like this:

```
{{> someCoolHelper
 someParam1='someVal1'
 someParam2='someVal2'
 someParam3='SomeVal3'
 someParam4=someAnotherHelper 'value param to this helper'
}}
```

So I have a function, that computes some value depending on parameter that can be passed in it. So how can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

as you may read in a forum thread at [meteor forum](https://forums.meteor.com/t/what-about-multiple-helper-calls-in-a-template-is-this-usefull/6815) this is not possible by now in spacebars.

We began with a new package for chaining methods and arguments but its not released yet. What you could do is to use the `WITH` element like

Instead something like:

```
{{> someCoolHelper
  someParam1='someVal1'
  someParam2='someVal2'
  someParam3='SomeVal3'
  someParam4=someAnotherHelper 'value param to this helper'
}}
```

can be managed by:

```
{{#with someAnotherHelper 'value param to this helper' }}
  {{> someCoolHelper
    someParam1='someVal1'
    someParam2='someVal2'
    someParam3='SomeVal3'
    someParam4=this
  }}
{{/with}}
```

I don't like it, but sometimes necessary

Tom

P.S.: Or drop Spacebars and use React - you won't have such limitations there.

Comment: Thanks for you answer, but I have a little bit another situation in my project.. With your variant this block of code works only if in "#with" condition exist some value. In my situation value that will be returned by that another helper can be empty (array with zero length, false, e.g)

Comment: It will not get better but you may use an {{if}} statement outside so that you are sure that #with will get a value otherwise go in an {{else}} statement. Sorry but thats spacebars.

Comment: `#with` is now deprecied because it update the context.. Use `#let` now

Answer (score 0):

The placeholder solution until template sub expressions are available in Spacebars is to create an helper returning the adequate value in JS :

HTML

```
{{> myTemplate param1="A" param2=param2}}
```

JS

```
function someOtherHelper(param){
  console.log(param);
}

Template.registerHelper("someOtherHelper", someOtherHelper);

Template.myTemplate.helpers({
  param2: function(){
    return someOtherHelper("B");
  }
});
```

Comment: As I understood your question, you was looking for a (dynamic) solution which is mostly done within the template source and not to code a number of wrapper functions with special calls like `return someOtherHelper("B")`. Correct?

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the output of a helper to another helper using parentheses. Pretty sure this is what you're after:
http://blazejs.org/guide/spacebars.html#Calling-helpers-with-arguments

> You can also pass the output of a helper to a template inclusion or other helper. To do so, use parentheses to show precedence:

```
{{> Todos_item (todoArgs todo)}}
```

> Here the todo is passed as argument to the todoArgs helper, then the output is passed into the Todos_item template.

Something I did in a recent project uses this functionality to allow conditional rendering of CSS classes to a component (stripped down for brevity):

```
# global helper to provide ternary operator
Template.registerHelper('ternary', (condition, resultTrue, resultFalse) => {
  return condition ? resultTrue : resultFalse
})

# in my-template.js:
Template.My_template.helpers({
  isComplete(score) {
    return score === 1
  }
})

# in my-template.html:
{{> some_component class=(ternary (isComplete this.score) "green" "red")}}
```